# XML Parsing Error Location: Part: /Word/document.xml, Line: x, Column: xxxx

Tags: xml, ms-word, document, corrupt

I have been trying for days to recover a word document that has become corrupted. the document.xml file is the culprit it is throwing up an error upon opening the document i am met with:

XML Parsing Error
Location: Part: /Word/document.xml, Line: 2, Column: 17062826
(Premature end of data in tag document line 2)

I have reformatted the document using the XML Tools plugin in Notepad++ and i cannot see any issue with the line referred to.
When opening this document in XML Marker it looks like the issue is at the end of the document on the closing tag.

Although to me it looks fine it looks like it is written correctly.
Im not great with xml so i really cant see what im supposed to change to fix this i have tried for days and also looked on the net and on here although people have the same issue and it is posted about i haven't been able to find anything that helps me understand what im looking at in the XML (again i am no good with xml code).

I would really appreciate any help with this so i can understand what i need to change and why. That way if it happens in future ill understand it.

When opening the xml it lags my computer for a few seconds so cant paste here but i have uploaded the whole xml here: http://www54.zippyshare.com/v/a0zZzBW7/file.html

Can anybody assist me with this because im loosing my mind here.
I have also take a screenshot of the file open in xml marker:
[image]
Below is the bottom part of the xml code:
Xml Marker says `Expecting <, </ or text`
i dont understand why or even where to put that as i thought `</x:xxxx>`. is the correct syntax to end the xml but some of you guys who know xml will be able to show me where i am going wrong here.

```
    <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId79"/>
                        <w:headerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId80"/>
                        <w:pgSz w:w="19200" w:h="10800" w:orient="landscape"/>
                        <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
                        <w:cols w:space="720"/>
                    </w:sectPr>
                </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run this through an XML validator to check if it gives you the same error? Also, you might want to download the OpenXml SDK. It has a tool for loading and parsing Office XML docs that might give you a better understanding of the error.

Comment: well theres a function within the xml pl;ugin in notepad++ that can validate and it does give the error and ill give the openxml a try thanks

Comment: openxml wont open it it says it contains corrupt data

Comment: Your file _likely_ has a corruption that isn't being displayed by the text editors then--something that's being read, but not displayed. This could be why the XML looks fine to you, but when read by other programs, it's erroring out. What does Notepad++ tell you is the encoding (regular Notepad will show this on the "Save As" dialog)?